# add other applications in pulse audio

Tags: sound, bluetooth, pulseaudio, skype

I use pulse audio ( pavucontrol) to manage my sound and tell which sound should come out on my blutooth headset and which sound should remain on speakers.
But I am not able to add applications, so at moment I have :
System sounds on my speakers
Chrome on my headset.

I d like to have skype also on my headset, but I don't find where I can add a program in this list.

  [image]

Comment: start a skype call, when skype is producing sound it will show in the list. then yu can set it to the headset

Comment: Thanks ! it works, please make a proper answer and i ll accept it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Applications have to be producing sound to show in the volume control.

Start a skype call. Once it appears in the list then you can set it to the headsets. Pulse will remember the setting.